# Can't pass rgb value through a variable

Tags: python, pygame

Not much to say, I create a variable

```
colour = (int, int, int)
```

and then I try to pass it in this way

```
self.img = self.my_font.render(self.unit_type, 1, self.colour)
```

the error I get is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/oricc/PycharmProjects/designAChessboardChallange/display.py", line 137, in <module>
    pw1 = Pikeman()
  File "C:/Users/oricc/PycharmProjects/designAChessboardChallange/display.py", line 90, in __init__
    self.img = self.my_font.render(self.unit_type, 1, self.colour)
TypeError: Invalid foreground RGBA argument
```

the complete code is the following

```
import pygame
import sys
from coordinator import coordinator

# Sets up the display

pygame.init()
window_size = (800, 800)
game_window = pygame.display.set_mode(size=window_size)
pygame.display.set_caption('My Game')


# Defines classes and related methods

class WhiteSquare:
    def __init__(self):
        self.height = int(window_size[0] / 8)
        self.width = int(window_size[1] / 8)
        self.white_square = pygame.Surface((self.height, self.width))
        self.white_square.fill((255, 255, 255))


class BlackSquare:
    def __init__(self):
        self.height = int(window_size[0] / 8)
        self.width = int(window_size[1] / 8)
        self.black_square = pygame.Surface((self.height, self.width))
        self.black_square.fill((0, 0, 0))


class ChessBoard:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ws = ws
        self.bs = bs
        self.white_columns = white_columns
        self.black_columns = black_columns

    def draw(self):
        for w_columns in self.white_columns:
            game_window.blit(self.ws.white_square, w_columns)

        for b_columns in self.black_columns:
            game_window.blit(self.bs.black_square, b_columns)


# class SquareNames:
#     letters = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H']
#     numbers = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8']
#     square_names = []
#     for letter in letters:
#         for number in numbers:
#             square_name = letter + number
#             square_names.append(square_name)
#     print((square_names))
#     # for coordinate in
#     # coordinates = (square_name : coordinate)

# TBC..........

# Background for units

class CircleSurface:
    def __init__(self):
        self.circle_surface = pygame.Surface((100, 100), flags=pygame.SRCALPHA)
        pygame.draw.circle(self.circle_surface, (0, 255, 0), (50, 50), 45)


class Unit:
    def __init__(self):
        self.surface = pygame.Surface((100, 100))
        self.my_font = pygame.font.SysFont('Time New Roman', 100)
        self.cs = cs

    def draw_circle(self, surface):
        pygame.draw.circle(self.cs.circle_surface, (0, 255, 0), (200, 200), 50)
        surface.blit(self.cs.circle_surface, (200, 200))


class Pikeman(Unit):
    unit_type = 'P'
    destination = (int, int)
    colour = (int, int, int)

    def __init__(self):
        self.r = int
        self.g = int
        self.b = int
        self.colour = (self.r, self.g, self.b)
        super().__init__()
        self.img = self.my_font.render(self.unit_type, 1, self.colour)

    def set_colour(self, colour):
        self.colour = colour

    def draw(self, surface):
        surface.blit(self.img, self.destination)


class Archer(Unit):
    unit_type = 'A'
    destination = (525, 525)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.img = self.my_font.render(self.unit_type, 1, (255, 0, 0))

    def draw(self, surface):
        surface.blit(self.img, self.destination)


class Knight(Unit):
    unit_type = 'K'
    destination = (325, 525)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.img = self.my_font.render(self.unit_type, 1, (255, 0, 0))

    def draw(self, surface):
        surface.blit(self.img, self.destination)

# Sets and gets the coordinates for black and white squares


coordinator = coordinator()

black_columns = coordinator[2] + coordinator[3]
white_columns = coordinator[0] + coordinator[1]

# Creates needed objects

ws = WhiteSquare()
bs = BlackSquare()
cb = ChessBoard()
cs = CircleSurface()

pw1 = Pikeman()
pw1.destination = (225, 625)
# pw1.colour = (0, 0, 255)
# print('pw1 colour' + str(pw1.colour))
pw1.set_colour((0, 0, 255))
print('colour' + str(pw1.colour))

pw2 = Pikeman()
pw2.destination = (325, 625)
pw3 = Pikeman()
pw3.destination = (425, 625)
pw4 = Pikeman()
pw4.destination = (525, 625)
kw1 = Knight()
kw1.destination = (125, 625)

kw2 = Knight()
kw2.destination = (625, 625)

aw1 = Archer()
aw1.destination = (225, 725)
aw2 = Archer()
aw2.destination = (325, 725)
aw3 = Archer()
aw3.destination = (425, 725)
aw4 = Archer()
aw4.destination = (525, 725)


# Event loop (outer)

while 1:
    # Event loop (inner)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
    # Draws needed objects and updates display

    cb.draw()

    # Draws white pieces in their initial position
    pw1.draw(game_window)
    pw1.draw_circle(game_window)
    pw2.draw(game_window)
    pw2.draw_circle(game_window)
    pw3.draw(game_window)
    pw3.draw_circle(game_window)
    pw4.draw(game_window)
    pw4.draw_circle(game_window)
    kw1.draw(game_window)
    kw1.draw_circle(game_window)
    kw2.draw(game_window)
    kw2.draw_circle(game_window)
    aw1.draw(game_window)
    aw1.draw_circle(game_window)
    aw2.draw(game_window)
    aw2.draw_circle(game_window)
    aw3.draw(game_window)
    aw3.draw_circle(game_window)
    aw4.draw(game_window)
    aw4.draw_circle(game_window)

    pygame.display.update()
```

as you can see from this chunk of code, and from all the variables I have created inside Pikeman(), I first tried to set the value for the colour variable directly, but then I tried to create a setter, well I can't make it work.

```
pw1 = Pikeman()
pw1.destination = (225, 625)
# pw1.colour = (0, 0, 255)
# print('pw1 colour' + str(pw1.colour))
pw1.set_colour((0, 0, 255))
print('colour' + str(pw1.colour))
```

Comment: What do you mean `self.r = int`? It changes the type of the variable `r`. If you add `print(type(self.r))` to the code you will get output as `<class 'type'>`.

Comment: I mean that if I declare the value as an integer that I can pass it as an integer, but obviously this is not the way. As far as I can understand RGB is 3 integers to pass as (int, int, int) .

Comment: you do not need to "declare" values in python. What you do sets type of variable as `type` and not `int`. Simply `self.r = 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry that does not work like that, your assumption is wrong. Of course, if the value of `self.color` is changed,

> ```py
> def set_colour(self, colour):
>    self.colour = colour
> ```

then each object which is drawn with the use `self.colour`, would be draw with the new color set.

Sadly `self.colour` is never used again to render anything. Note, `self.colour` is used in the constructor of the object to render a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html):

> ```py
> def __init__(self):
>    # [...]
>
>    self.colour = (self.r, self.g, self.b)
>    self.img = self.my_font.render(self.unit_type, 1, self.colour)
> ```

If you change the color which was used to render the `Surface` (image), then the image doesn't change magically.

When you change the color, then you've to render the `Surface` again:

```py
class Pikeman(Unit):
    unit_type = 'P'
    destination = (int, int)
    colour = (int, int, int)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.set_colour((0, 0, 0))

    def set_colour(self, colour):
        self.colour = colour
        self.img = self.my_font.render(self.unit_type, 1, self.colour)

    def draw(self, surface):
        surface.blit(self.img, self.destination)
```

Comment: I have just tried your code, but it gives a type error saying that set_colour() takes 2 positional arguments but 4 were given. That is because of I passes the 3 integers for rgb, but the method only takes colour (apart from self). I got now I have to render the surface again, but still can't pass colour as 3 integers...

Comment: @MirkoOricci It has to be a tuple of rgb values e.g. `(0, 0, 255)` respectively  `pw1.set_colour((0, 0, 255))`. Exactly as you do it in the code of the question.

Comment: Sorry, I was passing set_colour(0, 255, 0) instead of set_colour((0, 255, 0)). Another green tick for you mate.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the type `int` of class you initialize the rgb variables. I.e. if you gave alla zeros to the initial value it would be of a convienient type so you need to handle it differently.

```
def __init__(self):
    self.r = 0
    self.g = 0
    self.b = 0
    self.colour = (self.r, self.g, self.b)
    super().__init__()
    self.img = self.my_font.render(self.unit_type, 1, self.colour)
```

I am not saying this is the solution but here is your problem.

Comment: I was doing that, and I also managed to pass the value earlier on, but the actual text was still on the initial colour, although the print statement was showing the new values.